# With rejectUnauthorized: true Node does not accept the pfx certificate generated from pems and using c# httpClient for client side

Tags: c#, node.js, ssl, x509certificate, dotnet-httpclient

When I set rejectUnauthorized to false in the http options everything works fine.  Also when I use the pem certificate and key from curl everything works fine (even with rejectUnauthorized: true).

I generated the pfx from the pems like this...
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey private.key -out certificate.pfx

I checked the certificate against the CA like this:

openssl verify -CAfile ../ca-crt.pem crt.pem

crt.pem: OK

So  know the original pem file is verified by the CA I'm using.
Here's the handler in c#:

```
            Handler= new WebRequestHandler();
            Client = new X509Certificate2(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientpfx"],"pw");
            if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["checkCA"] == "y")
                new X509Certificate2(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CA"]);
            Handler.ClientCertificates.Add(Client);
            Handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = VerifyServerCertificate;
```

Here's where the client sends to the server:```
using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(Handler,false))

````
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), page))
            {
                var contentList = new List<string>();
                contentList.Add("connector=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectorname"] );
                contentList.Add("type=xml");
                contentList.Add("modality="+dicom);
                contentList.Add("data="+xml.Replace("&", "&amp;"));
                contentList.Add("html="+html.Replace("&", "&amp;"));
                request.Content = new StringContent(string.Join("&", contentList));
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var response = await Client.SendAsync(request);//Always getting connection closed unexpectly here
                var rtext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return rtext == "ok"; ```
````

Anyone know why node doesn't consider this pfx an authorized cert?

Comment: I think the issue is with X509Certificate2.  Recently an number of posting have had issues with upgrading old working project to latest Net Library and have gotten errors.  It seem Net now implements TLS 1.3 which is 64 bit mode.  I have not found the root cause of issues.  What I suspect the issue has to do with 32 bit mode encryption and 64 bit mode encryption.  And one posting did suspect the X509Certificate2 method.  You may want to read Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security   Is your certificate 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I made them like they did here. https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2  I think the keys are 4096 bits